# Blank cors policy block my request in expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, cors

i have this issue when sending request to server:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/distance' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

My CORS policy and ExpressJS server looks:

```
let PORT = process.env.PORT,
  MONGO_DB_URL = process.env.MONGO_DB_URL
const app = express();

if (process.env.MODE === "DEV") {
  PORT = 5000
  MONGO_DB_URL = `mongodb://localhost:27017/tt111`
  app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
  console.log("asd")
} else {
  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
mongodbConnection(MONGO_DB_URL);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/distance", roadRoutes());
app.use("/api/webStatsRoutes", webStatsRoutes());
app.use("/api/contact", contactRoutes())
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'))
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});
```

When server starts, display in console: "asd", so i have setup dev mode (look at if statement).

My request comes from react app working on localhost:3000.
My axios request:

```
 axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/distance`, data).then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    isLoading: false,
                    resultSearchedData: response.data.companies || [],
                })
                this.props.getAllCompanies(response.data.companies)

            }, (err) => {
                console.log("Axios error: " + err)
            })
```

I was trying with completly blank policy like this:

```
app.use(cors())
```

and with credentials:

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true,origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
```

Comment: In past, it was working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have swapped localhost with 127.0.0.1 as this usually is what causes this bug in development as it's a different address which is not specified in your cors policy.

Another possible problem is in this line:

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
```

Since you are running from a :5000 app your client side code you shuld switch this to 5000, you even set up the `PORT` variable so this might be a typo.

Comment: Client side is running on localhost:3000 not localhost:5000

Comment: @newmaster Ok! So the problem was with the 127.0.0.1 part?

Comment: no i setup origin to localhost:3000 and credentials true